# Displaying the Data in Table with using jQuery in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a data which i use PHP to access them. So i created a simple button, when i click on it, my programm needs to create a table with the data. **Below you can see the jQuery Code to read the data, and also create a table.** But the problem is, i can not access the each element in the DATA.
I want to make clear because of that i also add the code, which i make the selection in data. *Its called "household.php"*

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.2.js"
    integrity="sha256-pkn2CUZmheSeyssYw3vMp1+xyub4m+e+QK4sQskvuo4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    function suchen() {
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: "household.php",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {
            var data = JSON.parse(response)
            var html_table = "";
            data.forEach(function(item) {
              var row = $("<tr>");
              row.append($("<td>").text(item.contact_id_a));
              row.append($("<td>").text(item.contact_id_b));
              // add more cells for additional columns
              html_table += row[0].outerHTML;
            });
            $("#tabelle").html(html_table);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form" onsubmit="suchen()" method="get">
    <label>Enter your age: </label>
    <br />
    <input type="number" name="min" min="0">
    <br />
    <input type="number" name="max" min="0">
    <br />
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <div id="tabelle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here's the code for household.php file. It works without problem. But i can not connect between my main php file.**

```
<?php
    require_once '/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php';
    require_once 'CRM/Core/Config.php';
    $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
    
  $relationships = \Civi\Api4\Relationship::get()
  ->addSelect('contact_id_a', 'contact_id_b', 'contact_id_a.display_name', 'contact_id_b.household_name', 'relationship_type_id')
  ->addClause('OR', ['relationship_type_id', '=', 7], ['relationship_type_id', '=', 8])
  ->setLimit(25)
  ->execute();
  foreach ($relationships as $relationship) {
  // do something
}

    var_dump(json_encode($relationships));

?>
```

i can not access the data with php file. I also can not connect my main php file, with searching php.

Comment: First, replace `var_dump(json_encode($relationships));` with `echo json_encode($relationships);`. If you use var_dump, it adds extra text around the result, which will make it impossible for jQuery to parse the response as valid JSON. var_dump is only a debugging tool, it's not for general output

Answer (score 0):

I think you already used `echo json_encode($relationships)` in `household.php` file. You don't need the parse the response (you used ) because you already write `dataType` to `json`. it would automatically be converted. Hope this answer to help you. According to [jQuery Manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), "any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected". So you can use dataType: 'json' only, if you're sure, that server will return poperly formatted JSON. If it only returns "a string, that looks like JSON", you should use dataType: "text json" to force jQuery conversion.
[NOTE] If above answer doesn't help you, I suggest that you use this function for parsing response. `var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);` or `var data = $.parseJSON(response)`